# iPhone dev - how to store and retrieve data on sqlite server using RESTful services

Tags: ios, sqlite, rest, data-persistence

I am fairly new to iOS development, but have made an iPhone app that allows users to key simple contact info (name, email, phone, title) into a view that then stores it into a sqlite data base on my MAC. I am using the FMDB library to help with this. Now, I would like to use a RESTful web service to store the data on a server somewhere instead of on my MAC, but am not sure how to start. Any suggestions? Any libraries that would help?

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to keep your database on a server then it may be a better idea to have a MySQL or PostgreSQL database set up with a language like PHP or Python to serve as your back-end "server side" web framework. This will keep all of your queries and connections separate from the application itself. With this model your Objective-C written native app becomes a simple front end. This also allows you to write the app for other platforms like Android and/or a website without changing the server side code much.

Here's a nice tutorial on how to get started for an iPhone app: [link](http://www.raywenderlich.com/13511/how-to-create-an-app-like-instagram-with-a-web-service-backend-part-12).